# Multiply or Divide certain numbers on a projection file(?) of Japan

Tags: qgis, proj, japan

the title seems weird though, i am dealing with Japanese shapefile and it has its own "bizarre" projection.

I have two hints to solve this issue.

1. it's based on espg 4301 (http://pacificprojections.spc.int/4301#)
2. but the coordinates is in integer(?), it has to be transformed.
   for instance, the coordinates divided by (3600*1000)
   e.g.) 502888725, 128444858 => 139.6913125, 35.6791272

Within QGIS, it looks like i need to make custom CRS and fix proj.4 of ESPG 4301, which looks like below (i added +to_meter = 1/3600000)

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +towgs84=-146.414,507.337,680.507,0,0,0,0 +no_defs +to_meter=1/3600000
```

but obviously, it doesn't work.

Can anyone help for this?

when i define the projection to ESPG 4301 and open the file in ArcGIS, it shows the error message of extent issue.

Comment: or seems like i have to modify the coordinate of the shape file, internally. (like changing the extent..?) but how? :(

Comment: On thing to try - go into layer properties and recalculate the extent (from ArcCatalog, open layer properties and go to the Feature Extent tab.  Click recalculate).

Comment: @jbalk thanks for the comment. it did change the extent yet not showing any features on my arcmap display :@ hmm.... it's another headache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to scale the coordinates. You can do it with GDAL and SQLite/SpatiaLite SQL dialect http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html and the "ScaleCoords" function of SpatiaLite https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

I made a test with your example point by saving the WKT of it `POINT (502888725 128444858)` into OpenJUMP file japan_1.jml. Then I verified with ogrinfo that the scaling works as supposed. I had to convert the scale factor expression 1/3600000 first into number 2.7777777777777777777777777777778e-7

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select scalecoords(geometry,2.7777777777777777777777777777778e-7) as scaled_geometry from japan_1" japan_1.jml
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `japan_1.jml'
      using driver `JML' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (139.691312, 35.679127) - (139.691312, 35.679127)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = scaled_geometry
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  POINT (139.6913125 35.6791272222222)
```

Seems to work. What you need to do is to edit a -sql parameter so that it suits with your data. Command will look about like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -a_srs epsg:4301 -dialect sqlite -sql "select scalecoords(geometry,2.7777777777777777777777777777778e-7),attribute_1, attribute_2, attribute_3 from my_shape" my_scaled_shape.shp my_shape.shp
```

You must include all the normal attributes of your shapefile into list of selected fields in your SQL statement. Use `ogrinfo -al -so my_shape.shp` for reading the attribute list.

Comment: dayum.. this looks confusing but ti will try.
since i get the hint that i am going to do with "Scale", i will go for with ArcMap function though.

Comment: The syntax may look confusing but the idea is clear: multiply each coordinate by 1/3600000, save result into new shapefile. It is possible to update on place as well but to create a copy is more safe. I guess you could also use the QGIS Field calculator for scaling the coordinates.

Comment: i am new to QGIS stuff but i will try for tonight to figure this out. thanks for help and i will keep you updated!

Comment: It returned"FAILURE: no target datasource provided 
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers"

this error message. Trying to fix this :(

Comment: Paste you whole command, there must be some glitch in the syntax.

Comment: i pasted the command

[ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -a_srs epsg:4301 -dialect sqlite -sql "select scalecoords(geometry,2.7777777777777777777777777777778e-7),meshcode from JPN_Ocean" test.shp JPN_Ocean.shp]

did i do anything wrong?

Comment: I made a shapefile "JPN_Ocean" with an attribute "meshcode" and your command works for me. Try to write the whole command from keyboard, different character sets make often problem with copy-paste. The error means some problem in finding the output parameter "test.shp" from your command line.

Comment: funny... i copy and pasted the whole command. i realized that i am supposed to copy only the command in quotation mark. now it works just fine.
thanks for the tip. I do really appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use GUI the Affine transform tool of OpenJUMP is pretty simple to use. What you want to do is actually a simple affine transformation with only two parameters: x-scale and y-scale. With OpenJUMP you need to fill in these parameters and press OK.

[image]

Comment: OMG, this is so freaking easy to work with. Thanks for the comment. Now i think i should work with the GDAL command above. Cuz, i need a specific PRJ file for this!

thanks for help, srly. I've been digging this for 12 hrs :)