# FileGDB feature layer processing using OGR2OGR sqlite scalecoords

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, sqlite

This is an extended question of the following link :  [Multiply or Divide certain numbers on a projection file(?) of Japan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256476/multiply-or-divide-certain-numbers-on-a-projection-file-of-japan)

It works great with shapefiles but somehow it's not working well with FileGDB feature classes

Some of my layers are over 2GB; therefore, i had to store them as FileGDB feature class. I have installed FileGDB driver (using the latest version of GDAL) and modify the code shown in below

```
ogr2ogr -f "filegdb" -a_srs espg:4301 -dialect sqlite -sql "select scalecoords(geometry, 2.7777777777777777777777777777778e-7), ATTRIBUTES1, ATTRIBUTES2, from D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb\NAME_VS_E" D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb\test D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb\NAME_VS_E
```

and it returns an error
"Unable to open datasource'D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb\NAME_VS_E' with the following drivers.

[image]

I have installed the driver though.
It works great with

```
ogrinfo -so D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb
```

[image]

Mysterious....

Comment: At least the SQL part has couple of errors. They may not be real but come from copy-paste-edit but anyway, there must not be comma before from in `ATTRIBUTES1, ATTRIBUTES2, from` and from must point to the layer name as it is reported by ogrinfo, so simply just `NAME_VS_E`.

Comment: @user30184, oh thanks. I noticed that now. but still it shows it cannot open data source of my filegdb :(

Comment: The name of your filegdb is not `D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb\NAME_VS_E`. Because you use the -sql parameter you need to use just `D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb`. And as always in ogr2ogr syntax, the name of the datastore and the layer are separated with space. `D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb NAME_VS_E` should work, though not with -sql select that overrides the selection of layer. There is an even an example of the syntax in http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html.

Comment: @user30184, i think i am getting closer to the answer. I made the OGR to make another FGDB (since i am not going to overwrite the layer) and scalecoorded it and it gives me another message.

"no such column geometry"

I think it gives me the error, since FGDB layer has different geometry characteristics from shapefile layer.

Comment: Does `ogrinfo -so D:\NAME_VS_E.gdb NAME_WS_E` show some other name for the geometry field? By http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html it might be "SHAPE".

Comment: Tell the desired geometry type by running ogr2ogr with the -nlt parameter. It should be `-nlt POINT`if you still play with NAME_VS_E layer.

Comment: @user30184, yes you are right. It's SHAPE. thanks. .... and now it gives me another error. "FGDB layer cannot be created with a wkbUnknown". 

OOh, i was about to write that down. i used the -nlt option -nlt Linestring. it seems to work now. Thanks for help. I do appreciate.